# git reset --mixed delete newly added file?

Tags: git, github

I'm working with git on Github with a C++ project.
I have done the following in this order:

1. Codding existing and new `.cpp` and `.h` files. Also added a big `.stl` file.
2. Add the new files to git
3. Create commit "A" with this changes
4. Tried to push commit "A" to Github. It didn't let me push the commit because a file of 121MB had been added, which is more than the Github limit.
5. Used the `git reset --mixed` command so that I could undo the commit "A" containing the large file, add that file to .gitignore, and recreate a commit without that file.

Now the changes contained in files that were already tracked have remained and I can re-commit them, but the newly added files in commit "A" are all gone.

**Isn't the `git reset --mixed` command just undoing the commits without changing the files?**
**Is there any way to recover these files that I had just added to git and that have been deleted?**

Comment: a question, and an observation : a. `git reset --mixed` alone doesn't delete files from disk. Do you still see those "files that were newly added" on your disk, or in your IDE ? perhaps you just didn't `git add` them back before creating your new commit ?  b. the commit you created (the one with the big 121MB file) is still in your local reflog : the worse you would have to do is run `git reflog` to get the hash of that commit, and restore files from that specific commit.

Comment: I used the visual studio IDE to add new file and reset commit "A". All the files added just before commit A are no longer on the disk.  I didn't know the reflog, I was able to recover everything by doing a hard reset on the "A" commit. 
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the action that hides behind your IDE's "reset commit" isn't `git reset --mixed`, and it resulted in files being deleted from your disk.

---

As said in the comments : you can use the reflog to find past commits.

- run `git reflog` to spot the sha for commit `A` (the faulty commit with the 121MB file)
- use whatever action you see fit to get files back from that commit :

  - `git reset A`
  - `git checkout A -- file1 file2`
  - `git restore -s A -W -- .` or `git restore -s A -W -- file1 file2`
  - ...